# Python3 Multiple inheritance TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, multiple-inheritance, keyword-argument

I'm learning multiple inheritance in Python3. I'm wondering why the case# 1 works but case# 2 doesn't. Here are my code snippets.

```
class ContactList(list):
    def search(self, name):
        """Return all contacts that contain the search value
        in their name."""
        matching_contacts = []
        for contact in self:
            if name in contact.name:
                matching_contacts.append(contact)
        return matching_contacts


class Contact:
    all_contacts = ContactList()

    def __init__(self, name="", email="", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        Contact.all_contacts.append(self)
        print("Cotact")


class AddressHolder:
    def __init__(self, street="", city="", state="", code="", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.code = code
        print("AddressHolder")


class Friend(Contact, AddressHolder):
    # case# 1
    # def __init__(self, phone="", **kwargs):
    #     self.phone = phone
    #     super().__init__(**kwargs)
    #     print("Friend")

    # case# 2
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.phone = kwargs["phone"]
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Friend")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    friend = Friend(
        phone="01234567",
        name="My Friend",
        email="myfriend@example.net",
        street="Street",
        city="City",
        state="State",
        code="0123")
```

Here is the out put of the script. If I use only kwargs (case# 2) as a parameter in "Friend" that inherits "Contact" and "AddressHolder" then Python throughs error. I already tested the same type of construct without inheritance, except object, that worked perfectly.

```
"""
case 1#
$ python contacts.py
AddressHolder
Cotact
Friend
>>> friend.name
'My Friend'
>>> friend.phone
'01234567'
>>>
"""

"""
case 2#
$ python contacts.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "contacts.py", line 55, in <module>
    code="0123")
  File "contacts.py", line 43, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "contacts.py", line 16, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "contacts.py", line 25, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
>>>
"""
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let’s take a look at the method resolution order for `Friend`. This will tell us in what order the constructors will be called:

```
>>> Friend.mro()
[<class '__main__.Friend'>, <class '__main__.Contact'>, <class '__main__.AddressHolder'>, <class 'object'>]
```

So let’s take a look at case 1 first. These are the original named arguments to the `Friend` constructor:

```
phone="01234567"
name="My Friend"
email="myfriend@example.net"
street="Street"
city="City"
state="State"
code="0123"
```

Now, `Friend.__init__` takes `phone` as an explicit argument and then takes the rest as a keyword argument dictionary. so `kwargs` is the following:

```
kwargs = {
    'name': "My Friend",
    'email': "myfriend@example.net",
    'street': "Street",
    'city': "City",
    'state': "State",
    'code': "0123",
}
```

Next, `Contact.__init__` is called which takes the arguments `name` and `email`. This leaves `kwargs` like the following:

```
kwargs = {
    'street': "Street",
    'city': "City",
    'state': "State",
    'code': "0123",
}
```

Next, `AddressHolder.__init__` is called which takes the arguments `street`, `city`, `state`, and `code`. So `kwargs` is left as the following:

```
kwargs = {}
```

An empty dictionary! So the final call to `object.__init__` happens without passing any arguments, which is good because the `object` constructor does not accept any.

Now, let’s take a look at the second case now. Here, `phone` is not an explicit parameter of `Friend.__init__`, so it is passed as a keyword argument inside the dictionary. In all subsequent calls, the flow is exactly as above, except that `phone` is never taken out of the `kwargs` dictionary. So with the final call to `object.__init__`, `kwargs` will still look like this:

```
kwargs = {
    'phone': "01234567",
}
```

And that’s a problem for `object.__init__` because it does not accept a `phone` argument (or any really). So that’s why case two will fail here: Because there’s a remaining keyword argument that gets carried until `object.__init__`.

Comment: Thank you @poke for the nice explanation. Now things are getting more clear to me. Couldn't upvote because of my low reputation. However, this answer definitely changed my way of learning Python.

Comment: Please note that even calling object's `__init__` with empty `kwargs` like `{}` is not allowed!